How many graphs with $n$ vertices have a complete bipartite subgraph?
I don't work on graph theory, so let me clarify the definitions I'm using, which might differ from the usual ones (I hope not!). Given a graph with $V$ vertices and $E$ edges I'm calling "complete bipartite subgraph" to a new graph with $V$ vertices that can be divided into two groups $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that every vertex in $V_1$ is adjacent to every vertex in $V_2$, vertices on $V_1$ are not adjacent to each other and neither are vertices on $V_2$. For example, this is a complete bipartite graph:

and this one contains the previous one:

So both would fall under my category of "Graphs with four vertices that contain a complete bipartite subgraph".
I worked my question in two parts.

How many complete bipartite graphs with $n$ vertices are there?

I think the answer is $[\frac{n}{2}]$ where the brackets round to the closest lower integer. So for two vertices we can only build the complete bipartite graph $K_{1,1}$, for three vertices we can only build $K_{2,1}$, for four vertices we can build $K_{3,1}$ and $K_{2,2}$ and so on.

The question I still can't crack is: How many graphs with $n$ vertices will contain a complete bipartite graph? That includes the $[\frac{n}{2}]$ graphs I found earlier, but now we can add edges to them and the new graphs will still contain a complete bipartite graph as a subgraph.


So you're counting labeled graphs, not "graphs up to isomorphism".

@GerryMyerson If that's the case, we'd have many more than $\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ complete bipartite graphs.

This is easier to think about if we take the complement - turn all edges into non-edges, and vice versa.
A complete bipartite graph will turn into a disjoint union of two cliques. A graph that contains a complete bipartite graph will turn into a subgraph of that disjoint union - which is just to say, any disconnected graph. So the question becomes: how many disconnected graphs are there?
You appear to be counting graphs up to isomorphism, which is going to be harder. But the problem of counting all graphs up to isomorphism, and the problem of counting all connected graphs up to isomorphism, have both been well-studied. So excluding the connected graphs from the count should also produce a known sequence, and in fact it is sequence A000719 on the OEIS.
No simple formula for these is known. Asymptotically, we should expect the following quantities to be equal:

The total number of graphs on $n$ vertices.
The number of graphs on $n+1$ vertices with a vertex of degree $0$.
The number of disconnected graphs on $n+1$ vertices.
$2^{\binom n2}/n!$.

The intuition here is that, first of all, being disconnected is a very rare event, and that the least rare way for it to happen is for there to be a vertex of degree $0$. Second, that there are $2^{\binom n2}$ labeled graphs on $n$ vertices, and almost all of them have trivial isomorphism group, so dividing by $n!$ should account for the isomorphisms.
As a test case, if $a_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the OEIS sequence above, and if $b_n = 2^{\binom {n-1}{2}}/(n-1)!$, then $a_{87}$ and $b_{87}$ are both approximately $7.591591007565934 \times 10^{969}$, and $a_{87} - b_{87}$ is roughly $1.451376455987179 \times 10^{948}$. So the true value and the approximation agree in their $21$ leading digits, which seems pretty good to me!
